# git mv the whole repo one level up

Tags: git

StackOverflow community,

I have a git repository with this hierarchy:

```
(git-tree-root)
    software
        development
            project1
            project2
            ...
            projectX
        operational
            project1
            project2
            ...
            projectX
```

and I want to get a simpler hierarchy,

```
(git-tree-root)
    dev
        project1
        project2
        ...
        projectX
    op
        project1
        project2
        ...
        projectX
```

It is crucial that I maintain the file's git history.
My first thought is to do:

```
git mv -kr software/development/* dev/
```

and

```
git mv -kr software/operational/* op/
```

k flag is to ignore possible errors when moving files and the r flag is to move all files and folders recursively found inside the corresponding folders (development and operational). Then git add, and git commit changes.

Also, I want to make sure that in case there are users with files still "un-pushed" to the repo, they don't push them to the old hierarchy. Git should take care of this whenever they git pull my changes, correct?

It is important I get this right, so I would appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance eveyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
git mv software/development dev
git mv software/operational op
```

and if there is other cruft in `software` that you do not need anymore

```
git rm -r software
```

and then

```
git commit
```

Note that Git does not store file identities. "File history" is only reconstructed from the commit history. `git log --follow some/file` may help as long as you are investigating the history of just one file, but you may run into problems when the file contents have diverged sufficiently and you are comparing states before and after this event, because Git won't be able to correlate the two states to a "singe file".